# Financial Derivative, European Option

Tags: options, equities, put-call-parity, european, synthetic

Market Prices for European put and call options on ABC stock are as below:

Call = $4.5

Put = $6.8

Exercise Price, X =$70

Risk Free Annual Compounded rate r = 5%

Time to expiration T = 139 days

Current Stock Price S0 = $67.32

**A. Determine Synthetic call, put and stock prices using parity relations and explain your observation.**

Comment: Synthetic call = 4.5 - 6.80 + (70/(1.05))^139/360